# Facebook FQL Get All Posts At Location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The `location_post` [FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post) is described as the following:

> An FQL table that returns Posts that have locations associated with
>   them and that satisfy at least one of the following conditions:
>
> - you were tagged in the Post
> - a friend was tagged in the Post
> - you authored the Post
> - a friend authored the Post

So I wrote the following FQL script with the intent of getting all posts my friends and I had made at a certain location:

`SELECT id, message, post_id, timestamp FROM location_post WHERE page_id=303736809701751`

However, an empty data set is returned. In this particular case, I expect some of my own posts to be returned, though I have tried other place ids that should have returned friends' posts as well.

What is missing from the request, or is this a bug I should report to Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paragraph you quoted from the doc just says that the table **only** contains places where yourself and friends of yours have been. It tries to explain that you will not find public users there.

A query to the `location_post` table does not automatically specify the concerned IDs for you. If you want to search for the places where *all* your friends have been, you will have to indicate *all* your friends. If you are only interested by a bunch of friends, just add the concerned IDs.

This should do it.

```
SELECT id, message, post_id, timestamp
  FROM location_post 
 WHERE (author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
          OR author_uid = me() 
          OR tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
          OR tagged_uids = me()) 
       AND page_id = 303736809701751
```