# Retrieve Facebook posts from a location

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve all posts which are linked to a location. So I know how to retrieve locations (https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=XXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXX)

This returns locations like this:

```
{   "data": [
  {
     "category": "Local business",
     "category_list": [
        {
           "id": "209889829023118",
           "name": "Landmark"
        },
        {
           "id": "115090141929327",
           "name": "Park"
        }
     ],
     "location": {
        "street": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "country": "United States",
        "zip": "94114",
        "latitude": 37.759791,
        "longitude": -122.427027
     },
     "name": "Dolores Park",
     "id": "557140290973390"
  },
  {
     "category": "Local business",
     "category_list": [
        {
           "id": "152142351517013",
           "name": "Corporate Office"
        }
     ],
     "location": {
        "street": "88 Cumberland St, Apt 1A",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "country": "United States",
        "zip": "94110-1584",
        "latitude": 37.75923,
        "longitude": -122.42543
     },
     "name": "Terrarium Kits Corporate Headquarters",
     "id": "593264107360497"
  },
  {
     "category": "Local business",
     "category_list": [
        {
           "id": "115090141929327",
           "name": "Park"
        }
     ],
```

etc.

But I dont just want the locations, I want to retrieve all the public posts linked to these locations. Does anyone know how I can get those?

Thanks!

Comment: did you look on http://stackoverflow.com/a/17620802/2833802 ?

Comment: Yes, but than you can only retrieve posts that you are connected to in some way, so you have to be logged in. I want to retrieve all public posts from a location. But this is a good way to start, so thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Facebook Graph search functionality with 'type' set as 'place' and 'center' containing the latitude/longitude values. E.g.: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=insert access token

Once you have the id, you can then use it to get more information (e.g. the page url) via the Graph API. E.g.: http://graph.facebook.com/105687759464007402290636575506?fields=location,link,category,category_list,emails,website,name,name_with_location_descriptor